# Format ASP.Net MVC app for desktop and mobile browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mobile-website

I am working on an ASP.Net MVC application that with views that I want to be able to format for desktop browsers as well as mobile browsers.  Both formats would use the same Controllers and Actions but require different views.

What's the best way to do this?  Do I do a browser detect in the Action and then invoke the appropriate view?  Does the view do the browser detect and then render itself accordingly?  Is there something in between `return View();` and when the view actually is processed that I can override?

Thanks

Comment: Here: [Mobile Web Application Toolkit](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WebAppToolkitMobile). And don´t forget use WURFL.

Comment: Looks like the mobile web app toolkit is just what I need.  I've known about MDBF and had already planned on using it.  Thanks for the links!

Answer (score 6):

ScottHa has [this post about targeting multiple devices with ASP.NET MVC](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixMobileWebSitesWithASPNETMVCAndTheMobileBrowserDefinitionFile.aspx) addressing that same problem.

I would suggest either in the view or in something between the controller and the view (the ViewEngine...)

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with custom attributes stuffing appropriate views/masterpages around the returned Model. We use this tactic heavily for Ajaxification, shouldn't be difficult to extend the concept to mobile.

Comment: Interesting.  Can you give me more details?  Where do the attributes go?  How do you use the attributes to decide what view to use?  Do you have a custom view engine?

Answer (score 0):

I would detect the browser in the controller and return the appropriate view.  I guess you could override the view engine but that really seems like overkill to the extreme.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but it doesn't feel right to end every Action method with 

    if browser == mobile
        return view("mobile");
    else
        return view("desktop");