# MVC3 application custom route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to create a custom route that will see that if a coming request is from IPhone. If so then redirect to view 1 otherwise redirect to view2. How can I do it using MVC3 application.

Regards,
Asif Hameed

Answer (score 0):

I think this answers your questions:

[Format ASP.Net MVC app for desktop and mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670269/format-asp-net-mvc-app-for-desktop-and-mobile-browser)

Answer (score 0):

Good article here: [How to Add Mobile Pages](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/add-mobile-pages-to-your-aspnet-web-forms-mvc-application) from asp.net, about 3/4 of the way down specifically for doing this in mvc, also includes routing examples.

Comment: I need to do this only using the global.asax's custom route.